# Use of preposition "with" after the word "marry"

Tags: prepositions, collocation

Is it right to use the preposition "with" instead of "to" after the word "marry or married" under any given circumstances if we change the position of gender being mentioned?

For example:

"She is married to John"

Can we also say:

"John married with her" OR "John is married with her"

I highlighted this mistake in the notes of an educationist which he gave to his students. I raised this point with him that "to" is the only preposition which is used after the word "married". However, he argued that use of preposition depended on the position of gender being mentioned, thus the change in the position of gender also changes the preposition and it is right to use the preposition "with" after the verb "marry".

Can anyone explain?

Comment: I have never heard about the preposition choice depending on gender. How about if John is married to Paul, or Mary is married to Alice? _If_ there is such a gender-distinction, I'd see that as all the more reason to _only_ use "to". I know many Dutch people say "married with", because that is a literal translation from Dutch. I have always seen it as totally wrong in English though. I hope there will be an answer to shed some more light on this :)

Comment: @oerkelens: As a (Flemish) Dutch speaker myself, "Married With Children" made no sense to me for **years**, until a Brit explained why my version ("married to children") isn't actually valid in English.

Answer (score 4):

When talking about people it's either "She is married to him" or "She married him". When talking about objects the preposition "with" is used: "This wine marries well with beef"

Note: the above is an oversimplification - marry "with" was certainly used in past literature.
The following chart shows the relationship, married with is multiplied by 10 otherwise it just shows up as a line at the bottom. This also makes no attempt at separating things like "wine married to beef", which might explain, or not, the apparent increase of usage in the last 50 years

[image]

Comment: So if you objectify women or men, it _would_ be correct to use _with_ in case of people...

Comment: @oerkelens Can a person marry an object? The worst fears of gay marriage opponents have been realized.

Comment: The sad truth is that indeed marriage partners can be culturally seen as not much more than objects... If gay marriage opponents would aim their energy at that, I would support them :)

Comment: Although, in the Netherlands it used to be possible to marry a glove. This was done when the prospective husband would be away (e.g. at war).

Comment: @choster The internet says [yes](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/5972632/Woman-getting-married-to-fairground-ride.html).

Comment: @oerkelens indeed, personally, "married with" does sound objectifying "he married with her" sounds a bit like she didn't have much of a choice (but this is just a personal impression)

Comment: @msam: I wouldn't even bother thinking about any possible "objectification" implications of the preposition ***with*** here. It's vanishingly rare - even if you'd graphed ***married with her***, most hits would probably be for things like *with her **consent***. Or one particular Shakespeare usage: [she was respected with him before he married with her](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22with+him+before+he+married+with+her%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which would not generally be acceptable today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A better Ngram search might be _married with/to him_, since that won’t be able to double as a possessive determiner. That shows just how rare this really is: even multiplying _married with him_ by 10, _married to him_ is still [20–25 times more common](http://bit.ly/2p0U52N) (so with no multiplication it’s 200–250 times more common). Add to that the fact that the vast majority of the actual hits for _married with him_ are across punctuation (“…married. With him being…”) or non-native (“I tell her to married with him”), and you’ve got an almost nonexistent usage.

Answer (score 1):

"Marry with" carries the connotation of making the decision of getting married himself. It is more like of choice than of settlement by others in the family. Old Oxford English would provide the interested  learners with this explanatory usage and definition of the "marry followed by with". However, since ensuring gender discrimination has become the prime priority of the liberals, it has become more neutral using "to"after married.
Jhon was married with her : This gives the rational impression and  sense Jhon himself took decision to marry her. The usage of "with after married "is nowhere to be seen in the modern English---- It just makes sense in this way and is used in the old English in almost similar connotation.
She is married to Jhon : This connotes the sense she married Jhon , decided /arranged by someone else having ultimate decision to make.

Comment: Is there any source or support for these peculiar claims? (And *Jhon* is not an English name).

Answer (score 0):

I think we should use preposition 'to' while using married in passive construction i.e., [She is married to him] but we should use no preposition married is used in active voice i.e., [he married her].

Answer (score -5):

The preposition *with* seems to be fine in a context like:

> Prince William married **with** Kate Middleton

(Someone married Prince William with Kate Middleton)

Compare:

> Prince William married Kate Middleton

(Prince William did it)

also possible,

> Prince William married **to** Kate Middleton

Comment: +1 since I don't see why someone downvoted you. archaic: maybe, valid: why not?

Comment: The first and third examples in this answer are extremely awkward and unnatural.

Comment: @Tristanr Being awkward or unnatural is all about culture in this context, not grammar. I will be editing in more later on.

Comment: Kris, I have not heard anyone at all, use examples like them. If they are used, they must be exceptionally rare. They just sound awkward and different from everyday English.

Comment: @Tristanr Does that add anything to your previous comment?